# How to use drupal services in ionic 3 and angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drupal-7, ionic3

I want to create a hybrid app in which i want to use drupal 7 services as backend and ionic 3 and angular 4 as frontend. I searched a lot but didn't get any solution that how to use drupal services in ionic 3. can anyone help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe read a bit more about http requests? Server client architectures?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has [**RESTful Web Services**](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws). So you can consume those rest services through your Ionic app easily.

> Ionic3/Angular app --> Ionic Provider --> Drupal Resrfull service